# Ace editor "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18" in Chrome when running locally (no server)

Tags: ace-editor

I'm trying to run Ace editor from file system for now and in Chrome I'm getting:

```
"SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"
```

FireFox doesn't mind it.

Found this on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ace-discuss/oG0eenv3FbA/_O2ce4NZUBYJ):

> due to same origin restrictions workers can't be loaded from cdn  you
>   need to put them on your site, and add  ace.config.set("workerPath",
>   "path/to/ace/src-min");

No joy.

I'm initializing the editor like so:

```
<script src="js/source-editor/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    ace.config.set( "workerPath", "js/source-editor/src-min-noconflict");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/css");
</script>
```

Am I missing something hopelessly simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what's it worth, issue disappears one deployed to server.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full solution but it may help:

```
editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
```

This turns off worker, probably destroying performance in the process. It should probably be conditional on whether you are a local file by checking the url.